# Is there a way to modify a JCR node without changing its timestamp?

Tags: aem, jcr

Is there a way to modify a JCR node, but keep its `jcr:lastModified` and `jcr:lastModifiedBy` properties unchanged?

And by modifying, I mean via the JCR API. For example:

```
aNode.setProperty("propName", aValue);
```

Comment: From where? You need to be more specific in what you are trying to do. I think via groovy console you can update some node properties and keep those properties intact. Not sure. I'll try and come back.

Comment: the jcr:created and jcr:createdBy never get changed after the node gets created. Are you talking about the cq:lastModified and cq:lastModifiedBy?

Comment: @Bogdan @Thomas Apologies a heap! I was asking about `jcr:lastModified` and `jcr:lastModifiedBy` properties. And when executing `node.setProperty(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for the most cases. There are basically two options how a node retrieves both properties and get's them updated.
Either through some higher level API like CQ's PageManager, which is applying it on the jcr:content node or by the repo if the node has the mixin type mix:lastModified in it's type hierarchy.

```
[mix:lastModified]
  mixin
  - jcr:lastModified (DATE) autocreated
  - jcr:lastModifiedBy (STRING) autocreated
```

In this case the properties are automatically managed through the repository.

So you should be fine, as long as you avoid to create nodes with the mentioned mixin in it's type hierarchy e.g. nt:resource.

Comment: jcr:lastModified is NOT automatically set by Jackrabbit or Oak repository implementations. If they would, these properties would have to be defined as protected, see the spec. What happens is that AEM will update these on the application level for all cq:Pages and some other types.